# In Matlab, can the same number in double precision be bigger than the same number in integer format?

Tags: matlab

I have the following quandary in Matlab, can the same number in double precision (380.0000) be bigger than the same number in integer format (380)? Here is the example of the given problem:

```
K>> maxWeightsSum

maxWeightsSum =

380.0000

K>> solutionsSumSorted(1)

ans =

380

K>> maxWeightsSum>solutionsSumSorted(1)

ans =

 1
```

Comment: I bet the first one isn't exactly 380.  Try doing one minus the other.

Answer (score 1):

No, but what is happening is not that. Your `maxWeightsSum` is not exactly 380, its a big bigger but you are not displaying it. Matlab by default does not display the whole number, but those 4 zeroes should give you a hint that there is some value after them. Also, you can check the workspace variables, and you should be able to see the whole number.

Try the following code:

```
exact=380;
bigger=380.00000001;

format short % Tell matlab to display only 4 digits after the coma (this is default)

exact
bigger

format longG   % Tell matlab to display the whole number

exact
bigger
```

In general, you'd want to set the [`format`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) of your display to your needs.

**EDIT:** it seems that in some cases, this is not enough. However, I'll leave the answer here as I feel its important to know.

Comment: Even 'format long' does not show you the "whole number". Does anybody know how to view the actual number at full resolution?

Comment: @biguri, that won't be enough. try:
sprintf('%16.16f',x)
ans =
1.7320508075688772
>> 1.7320508075688772==x
ans =
     1
>> format longG
>> x
x =
          1.73205080756888

Comment: @mousomer You are rigth.

Comment: @mousomer Use `format hex`. That will show you a full representation of the number MATLAB is storing.

Comment: Ah. But reading the number in hex is a feat not meant for mere mortals.

Answer (score 1):

try to display it using sprintf:

```
x=sqrt(3)
x =   1.732050807568877
sprintf('%16.16f',x)
ans =
1.7320508075688772
```

and then

```
 1.7320508075688772==x
 ans =
 1
```